# Microsoft partitioned / 18.04 can't boot - Failed to start LSB: Lightweight intrusion detection system - UID 120

Tags: boot

I can't boot.
I run Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows partion.
I haven't uploaded anything new. Not sure what is going on.
Originally suggested it could have been Snort. I uninstalled but nothing chaged.

Still stuck on this UID 120

The computer shoes this at booting time and then it gets stuck here [image]

Comment: What does "the computer goes crazy" mean?

Comment: @ Organic Marble. Euphemism for it does not follow normal booting routine.

Comment: What is the systemctl command that is cut off in the picture? `systemctl status` something.

Comment: @ Organic Marble  snort.service

Comment: Did you just install snort? Suggest you boot into recovery mode and do the suggested systemctl command.

Comment: @ organic marble  I don't even know what snort is to be honest.  :-)  So the answer would be no, I didn't. Not sure what is going on. This started a week ago.

Comment: It's not installed on my systems, so I'm giving up here, but googling your message and snort turns up a lot of people with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to uninstall it? Not sure how to do steymctl.  I am not a techie or ubuntu  expert at all.  Do I need Snort? I don't even know how it got in the machine

Comment: Removing Snort did not help.